# Size of dispersed phase particles in colloid?

Tags: mixtures

I am really confused about what the size of particles of dispersed phase in a colloid is: one of my textbook says its between $1 - 100nm$, another says its between $1-1000nm$, and Wikipedia says its between $2-500nm$. Is there any reliable source giving the exact information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its between $1-1000nm$ as stated on [wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colloid) in a paragraph name `IUPAC definition`.

> Colloid: Short synonym for colloidal system.
>   Note: Quotation from refs.[3][4]
>   Colloidal: State of subdivision such that the molecules or polymolecular particles dispersed in a medium have at least one dimension between approximately 1 nm and 1 μm, or that in a system discontinuities are found at distances of that order.[5]
>   Note: Quotation from refs. [3],[4]

Edit: Since it is mention under IUPAC definition that size lies between $1nm-1000nm$, therefore this must be the correct size.

Comment: Does the term "polymolecular particles" mean cluster of molecules?